# Angular mat-select multiple - show the last selected values after changing the array

Tags: angular, typescript, multi-select

I have an object like this:

```
var cars = [
    { id: 1, name: "car1", sold: true },
    { id: 2, name: "car2", sold: false },
    { id: 3, name: "car3", sold: true }
    { id: 4, name: "car4", sold: true }
    { id: 5, name: "car5", sold: false }
]
```

I use reactive forms. My HTML:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Cars</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="carIds" multiple required>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let car of cars; [value]="car.id">
        {{car.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

So when i open my shopForm i see selected cars (saved in DB), f.e. car1, car2, car5.
Now I want to change the original Car array so that it only contains objects with "sold:true" :

```
var carsSold = [
    { id: 1, name: "car1", sold: true },
    { id: 3, name: "car3", sold: true }
    { id: 4, name: "car4", sold: true }
]
```

But when i use this array in HTML i see only car1 on form, because car2 and car5 are now missing from the list.
So i want see car1,car2,car5 (as saved on DB) from Сar and use carsSold as a drop-down list

[image: SelectedCars]
[image: CarsSold]

How can I implement this?

Comment: where do you want to see the car1, car2, car5 if not in the drop-down list?

Comment: Mr.Stash, edited original post

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that it is possible to remove the items from the options array and still display the items in the input field but you can hide the options

- Use ngClass and a condition to enable the ngClass condition.
- Set showOnlySoldCars flag to true or false to show or hide the unsold cars in the options.
- In your main styles file, styles.css add the class hidden-car-option.

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Cars</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="carIds" multiple required>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let car of cars">
        <mat-option [ngClass]="{'hidden-car-option': !car.sold && showOnlySoldCars}" [value]="car.id">
          {{car.name}}
        </mat-option>
      </ng-container>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

```css
.mat-option.hidden-car-option{
    display: none;
}
```